# Templated constructor arguments do not seem to care about their type if they are derived from a non-templated base class (Armadillo)

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, armadillo

I have the following two classes (contrived example):

```
#include <armadillo>

template<typename T>
class A : public arma::vec3
{
public:

     using arma::vec3::vec3;
};

template<typename T>
class B
{
public:

    B(const A<T>& a) {}
};
```

When running the following code:

```
int main()
{
    A<int> a;

    B<int> b_i { a };     // Should always pass.
    B<double> b_d { a };  // Should fail as template type is different between class and constructor argument.
}
```

I would **expect** the error at the bottom of this page because the object b_d has a template type double and the template type in the constructor of B is the same as the template of the class B, but **This code passes without any problems, which is not right.**

If I remove the inherited arma::vec3 constructor(s), however:

```
#include <armadillo>

template<typename T>
class A : public arma::vec3
{};

template<typename T>
class B
{
public:

    B(const A<T>& a) {}
};
```

I get the expected behaviour (the compile-time error):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘B<double>::B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
 B< double > b_d { a };  // Should fail as template type is different between class and constructor argument.
```

I am not an expert on templates and I do not know the inner workings of the armadillo vector library, but can anyone think of any reason why inheriting the arma::vec3 constructor(s) breaks my code (by not throwing the error)? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because `A<T>` (for any `T`) is a `vec3` (because of the inheritance), and you are `using` the `vec3` constructors which according to [the documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) includes a copy-constructor, the `A<T>` object will happily be copy-constructed from *any* `vec3` object.

When you do `using arma::vec3::vec3` you're copying the `vec3` constructors into the `A<T>` class without modifications, it basically creates a `A(const vec3&)` constructor, not a `A(const A&)` constructor.

---

When you don't have the `using` part, then the compilers auto-generated copy-constructor will be the only copy-constructor available for the `A<T>` class, and it will be `A(const A&)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I observe the same pattern when the I remove the member `A<T> _a` from `B` and make the constructor do nothing: `B(const A<T>& a) {}`. Since  `a` is passed by (const) reference, I don't see where the `arma::vec3` copy constructor would be called, as I don't see any objects of type `A` being created. Am I incorrect in my understanding of passing by reference to a constructor? Or is something else going on here? I have edited the question to reflect the aforementioned changes.